# Gatsby manual code splitting for single pages

Tags: gatsby

I know that Gatsby uses code splitting to optimize bundles for each given page, but how do we deal with it when creating a page as a single page application (like mentioned in [Client-only routes](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/)).

If I have an `app.js` like this (taken from the [example](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/simple-auth/src/components/PrivateRoute.js)):

```
import React from "react"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import Details from "../components/Details"
import Home from "../components/Home"
import Login from "../components/Login"
import PrivateRoute from "../components/PrivateRoute"
import Status from "../components/Status"

const App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Status />
    <Router>
      <PrivateRoute path="/app/profile" component={Home} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/app/details" component={Details} />
      <Login path="/app/login" />
    </Router>
  </Layout>
)

export default App
```

How can we achieve code splitting for these routes? Let's say `Details` is a very expensive component. Now it would be bundled and loaded everytime, no matter if it will be rarely visited.

Can we come around this?

Comment: Are you trying to lazy load an expensive component?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I've multiple routes within a single Gatsby page and one of those routes is expensive and rarely used.

Comment: is this creating pages using gatsby-node.js ? i want to ask about that,but i on't understand if this is the same thing..

Answer (score 2):

You can use React.lazy:
If `Details` is very expensive. Instead of

```
import Details from "../components/Details"
```

do

```
const Details = lazy(() => import("../components/Details"))
```

Note: you also need to add fallback component using `Suspense`:

```
  <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
    <Router>
      <PrivateRoute path="/app/profile" component={Home} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/app/details" component={Details} />
      <Login path="/app/login" />
    </Router>
  </Suspense>
```

Check out React's official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this segment](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-04-02-behind-the-scenes-what-makes-gatsby-great/#modern-apis-in-gatsby) of their blog post. Here the important section:

> gatsby-link and link rel="prefetch"
>
> The Link component exported by gatsby ships with an
>   IntersectionObserver. The behavior is two-fold:
>
> ```
> An IntersectionObserver is registered for all links
>     This will register an idle prefetch for a request for that link’s resources
>     See the code for gatsby-link
> On hover a fetch will be used to send a non-idle request for that link’s resources
>     This will use an onMouseEnter prop to make the resources available via our internal loader
>     See the code for gatsby-link
> ```

The solution is astonishingly simple:

> Use a classic HTML a tag instead of Gatsby Link.

This way the prefetching is disabled as discussed in this [issuee](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/13759#issuecomment-488366263) by the Gatsby project maintainers.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think I expressed myself unclear. I've edited my answer with an example.